How to set font for konsole super-user mode
I want to set the font used by konsole when running in super-user mode from the KDE applications menu.
When is superuser mode, the Settings menu does not include 'Edit Current Profile' as it does in normal user mode. If I select 'Manage profiles' and the click on Root Shell, the edit button is disabled. I tried using an editor to edit '/root/.local/share/konsole/Root Shell.profile' and explicitly set the font - that doesn't work. I tried 'Edit Applications' to edit the Command Line Arguments for 'Terminal - Super User Mode' to say
'-profile /root/.local/share/konsole/Root Shell.profile', but then I don't get a root shell at all. There seems to be some special decoding if the Command Line Arguments say exactly --profile 'Root Shell', which makes it do a root login shell rather than a shell for the user logged in to KDE. However I can't find where it gets root's profile from: it seems to be using the built-in one which I can't edit.
